# A simple question about generated subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(e_k)_k$ be an orthonormal sequence and $(x_k)_k$ be a sequence of linearly independent vectors. If we know that $$\text{sp}(e_1,\dots, e_k)=\text{sp}(x_1,\dots, x_k)\quad\text{for all}\quad k\ge 1$$ can I conclude that $$\text{sp}(e_k\;|\; k\in\mathbb{N})=\text{sp}(x_k\;|\;k\in\mathbb{N}).$$ If the answer is yes, for what reason?

Comment: Yes, because $\text{sp}(e_k\;|\; k\in\mathbb{N})=\bigcup_n sp(e_1,e_2,..,e_k)$ and $\text{sp}(x_k\;|\; k\in\mathbb{N})=\bigcup_n sp(x_1,x_2,..,x_k)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v\in sp(e_k | k\in \Bbb{N})$. Thus, there exists vectors $e_m,\dots,e_k$ for $m\le k$ such that $v\in sp(e_m,\dots,e_k)$. Clearly $$sp(e_m\dots,e_k)\subseteq sp(e_1,\dots,e_k)$$

Given that $sp(e_1,\dots,e_k)=sp(x_1,\dots,x_k)$, we have that $v\in sp(x_1,\dots,x_k)$. Because $$sp(x_1,\dots,x_k)\subset sp(x_k | k\in \Bbb{N})$$

We have that $v\in sp(x_k | k\in \Bbb{N})$ and thus $sp(e_k | k\in \Bbb{N})\subset sp(x_k |k\in \Bbb{N})$

---

Prove the inclusion in the other direction(prove that $sp(x_k | k\in \Bbb{N})\subset sp(e_k | k\in \Bbb{N}))$ to conclude that $$sp(e_k | k\in \Bbb{N})=sp(x_k | k\in \Bbb{N})$$